# equivalent GET request in node environment and browser not showing the same results

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I am starting to delve a bit more deeper into node.js and am playing around in the termianl. I am making a `GET` request, using the `got` node package https://www.npmjs.com/package/got

Below is both my code using `jquery` in the browser and `got` in the terminal.

**jQuery Code**

```
$.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/notwaldorf/emoji-translate/master/bower_components/emojilib/emojis.json', function (data) {
   var showEmoji = JSON.parse(data)
   console.log(showEmoji.grinning.char);
 })
```

This displays  in the broswer's console as I expected -- all is good.

Then when I write the equivalent code in the node environment, nothing is displayed.

**Node.js code**

```
var got = require("got");
var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/notwaldorf/emoji-translate/master/bower_components/emojilib/emojis.json'
got(url).then(function(data){
    var showEmoji = JSON.parse(data)
    console.log(showEmoji.grinning.char);
});
```

As far as I can tell node does recognise these emoji symbols -- see screenshot

[image]

Can anyone shed any light on why the results are not the same? Am I missing something simple and obvious?

It doesn't appear that the issue is to do with the emoji, as if I try change the code in the callback funxtion to the below, still nothing is displayed in node, but an array is displayed in the browser console.

```
console.log(showEmoji.grinning.keywords);
```

Comment: could you try to `console.log("")` in node ?

Comment: see screenshot attached

Comment: The font that you are using in console doesn’t support emoticons?

Comment: Have you tried changing the URL and retrieving JSON data from a different source? Or just logging something benign like `"hello"` to both consoles? Test lots of different inputs and compare them

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski why this edit ?

Comment: @Hacketo it is time to learn JavaScript standard API, say hello to 2016 year where jQuery is not required toolbox for everything

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski well it's not OP code ... also OP is not about jQuery but nodejs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `data` is not a string, it's a rich object describing the HTTP request. This code works:

```
var got = require("got");
var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/notwaldorf/emoji-translate/master/bower_components/emojilib/emojis.json'
got(url).then(function(data){
    var showEmoji = JSON.parse(data.body);
    console.log(showEmoji.grinning.char);
});
```

...but you really should be adding `.catch( ... )` calls to your promises, to alert you when this kind of thing happens. (There's also a common callback `.done()` but the promises from `got` don't seem to support it.)

The reason it didn't work is that the `JSON.parse` function is failing — but the reason Node didn't tell you about that is that exceptions in `.then()` callbacks aren't shown to the user. They're stored and passed into `.catch()` callbacks or thrown when you call `.done()`. Generally, you should never use `.then()` without `.catch()` existing *somewhere* or else this kind of thing will keep happening.

It would be lovely if all this explicit handling wasn't needed but that was never possible with promise libraries. Perhaps native promises will allow it in the future.

Comment: that works, thanks! However, I still don't understand why the same request works differently in the browser and in the terminal. It appears the same data is not being returned. If I do `console.log(typeof data)` in the terminal it returns object but in the browser it returns `string`

Comment: @Andrew Taylor, can you explain why it returns an `object` in node, but a `string` in the browser?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald The request works exactly the same — the difference is you're using jQuery in the browser and Got on Node. jQuery is programmed to return the body text because its devs presumably thought that would be most helpful for you, whereas Got's devs evidently thought you might want more information about the request than that, and so programmed Got to supply it. Neither is wrong — you just need to make sure you code for the right one.